# Carl Sagan—A Blast from the Past

Tags: visual, steganography

We all (hopefully) know that Carl Sagan was an accomplished astronomer, cosmologist, astrophysicist and an all-around deep thinker:

[image]

But he couldn't possibly have just sat around all day cogitating about giant black holes and vast clouds of interstellar gas, right?

> What do you think was on his mind at *this* moment?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The very deep, philosophical thought on Carl's mind is

> In space, no-one can hear you fart.

So I guess it turns out he **did** just sit around cogitating giant black holes and vast clouds of interstellar gas, hur hur.

---

As Phylyp said, the answer is a GIF with 8 frames.

> Frame 8 is *not* the answer; it indicates we should keep looking.

So instead if we take a look at frame 7 we see...

> A very faint QR code.

Which looks like this (separate spoiler block because formatting is being weird).

> [image: QR code]

Adjusting that to make it easier to scan, we get this:

> [image: QR code]

Scanning that gives us the answer.

Comment: No mention of the puzzle's Title in your answer, huh? :(

Comment: @Chowzen there are only so many puns I expect in one puzzle - at first I didn't even notice the interstellar gas ;-)

Answer (score 9):

The image is a GIF image, more specifically, it is

> An animated GIF with 8 frames, of which the last one is:
>  [image]
>
>  This is [a quote attributed to Carl Sagan](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/147806-we-can-judge-our-progress-by-the-courage-of-our):
>  - *“We can judge our progress by the courage of our questions and the depth of our answers, our willingness to embrace what is true rather than what feels good.”*
>
>
>  Note: The first 6 frames are the same picture of Sagan himself, the 7th frame is just the star field shown behind the quote, and the 8th is the image shown above.

Comment: Ooooh! I *knew* someone would take the bait, sorry it was you, @Phylyp!  :) Your answer would somewhat contradict the essence of what Carl was saying in the quotation, no?

Comment: It should be noted that the answer is ***not*** retrievable from the picture posted in this answer... please refer to my original picture.

Comment: Ha ha, nice one. Though the absence of a steganography tag is partly why I didn't look further (the other reason was I thought I had it).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, the stenography tag didn't occur to me.